# Disabling icons from appearing on the task bar doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I wanted to select some icons to be disappeared from the taskbar. But as you see from the screenshot, it doesn't work at all:

[image: screenshot]

I disabled the appearance of "DisplayLink Ui Sys-Try Application", but it's still visible on the task bar.

Answer (score 1):

What you essentially did was remove the icon from the System Tray, which can be accessed by clicking the up-arrow on the right side of your taskbar. In Windows 10, this is how the system tray looks like.

[image: Windows System Tray]

To remove the icon from the taskbar, you can simply right-click on the icon in the taskbar and click on 'Unpin from Taskbar'.

Hope this helped.

Comment: (+1) I agree - that is what I do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think, there's a misunderstanding. I don't want to remove the icons. I only want to hide them. To explain better: I want to have the numbers of visible icons short. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: @honeybee The solution I have given just removes the icon shortcuts from the taskbar. You can add the 'icons' i.e. the shortcuts back. If you meant making the icons invisible, then you'll have to tweak the taskbar.

Comment: Well, I tested it on a different computer. There it worked and I could make the icons invisible by turning off the equivalent icon in System -> Notifications & actions -> Select which icons appear on the taskbar. There is no need to tweak the taskbar. It's just a Windows problem that it doesn't work on the affected computer.